# Lein check: case has int tests, but tested expression is not primitive

Tags: clojure, switch-statement

I'm writing the standard higher/lower guessing game, but with an "AI" (although that's a generous term).

The function below takes the lowest and highest number in a range of numbers, the previous guess, and the "direction", which represents whether or not the previous guess was too low, too high, or correct, and returns the new range of numbers to guess.

```
(defn new-range [min-n max-n guess direction]
  (case direction
    1 [min-n guess]
    -1 [guess max-n]
    0 [guess guess]))
```

When I run this function through `lein check`, it gives me an error/warning:

```
case has int tests, but tested expression is not primitive.
```

And points at `(case direction`.

What does this mean? I searched for it, but all I could find were references to the source where this error is defined.

Is this anything I should worry about? I tried type-annotating `direction`, but that didn't change anything.

Edit: It turns out when I tried annotating `direction`, I accidentally used the boxed-type `Long`. Whoops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1, -1, and 0 will be primitive longs. check is telling you that the arg direction is not a primitive long (could be a Long object instead).

Type-hinting the direction arg should fix it:

```
(defn new-range [min-n max-n guess ^long direction]
  (case direction
    1 [min-n guess]
    -1 [guess max-n]
    0 [guess guess]))
```

Or casting direction to a long with `(long direction)` in the case should work:

```
(defn new-range [min-n max-n guess direction]
  (case (long direction)
    1 [min-n guess]
    -1 [guess max-n]
    0 [guess guess]))
```

I don't think the behavior will differ across any of these, it will just help slightly with performance.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that in a sec.

Comment: `direction` is actually just literals from another function, so unless they're being implicitly boxed somewhere, they should be primitive.

Comment: Clojure uses boxed numbers by default across all function boundaries, so Clojure is boxing them on the call. Type hinting will stop that from happening as Clojure will pass it through unboxed.

Comment: You were right. Both your ideas resolve the warning. Thanks.

Comment: Rofl. So for some reason I decided to look up "clojure unchecked math", and I stumbled on: http://insideclojure.org/2014/12/15/warn-on-boxed/. The internet is so small :0

Comment: You can annote returns!? Mother of god. Time to update my library.

Comment: For some reason it isn't possible to type hint something that has been destructured like: `[min-n max-n guess {:keys [^long direction]}]`. In those cases it seems necessary to opt for wrapping: `(long direction)` instead.